# Почему не получается сделать мок FindAsync с помощью NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mocking, nsubstitute

Сделал `Setup` метод для тестов, но почему-то, когда в тесте вызывается метод репозитория с `FindAsync` вылетает ошибка `Can not find an argument of type System.Guid to this call.`

```
public void Setup()
{
    data = new List<ModelEntity> { new() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), FieldOne = "A" };
    var mockSet = data.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();
    var mockContext = Substitute.For<IApplicationContext>();

    mockContext.ModelsTable.Returns(mockSet);
    mockContext.ModelsTable.FindAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>()).Returns(callInfo => data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == callInfo.Arg<Guid>()));

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ModelEntity, Model>());
    var mapper = new Mapper(config);

    repository = new StudentsRepository(mockContext, mapper);
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал еще заменить строку в `Setup` на:

```
mockContext.ModelsTable.FindAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>()).Returns(callInfo => data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == (Guid)callInfo[0]));
```

Но тоже вылетает ошибка, что невозможно сделать каст `System.Object[]` в `System.Guid`.

Comment: Не нужно мокать FindAsync! Не нужно мокать DbContext. Потому что не нужно тестировать метод репозитория, в котором нет бизнес-логики. / Это главное правило: тестируйте только бизнес-логику. Если метод репозитория является простой обёрткой метода EF, то бизнес-логики в нём нет, тестировать нечего. / Тестируйте свой код уровнем выше. Тот код, в котором используется репозиторий. И, соответственно, мокайте методы репозитория.

Comment: У метода FindAsync нет перегрузки, принимающей Guid. Он принимает object.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov но у меня, например, есть получение данных из таблицы с пагинацией в репозитории. Как это можно протестировать? Вынести в доменный слой и там тестировать?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov то есть сделать получение всех моделей в репозитории и уже в доменном слое делать пагинацию?

Comment: [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/). Я всегда тестировал на реальной БД (production database). / [Здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2) описан вариант, который похож на ваш способ. Но он давно не рекомендуется.